# piping output to uniq or sort -u not returning expected result

Tags: bash

I have tens of thousands of files that have names with similar, often repeating prefixes. I want to loop through all filenames and get a list of unique prefixes.

> AB-61-GA_0001c.txt
>   AB-61-GA_aseguh.xml
>   AM-81-BU_0678.mp4
>   AM-81-BU_ochyu.doc
>   AM-92-LA_gatyt.csv

I want to end up with output:

> AB-61-GA
>   AM-81-BU
>   AM-92-LA

For that I've put together the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.*
do
    UNIQUEOBJECT=$(echo "$i" | cut -d '_' -f 1 | sort -u)
    echo "$UNIQUEOBJECT"
done
```

For some reason I end up with the list of prefixes (everything before the underscore) with identical prefixes still repeating. Obviously this is just a lack of understanding of bash scripting on my part but what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your for loop is sending one filename at a time.  So you sort and unique a single filename.

You could do something like (syntax may not be quite right as I don't have a Linux box for testing at the moment)

```
#!/bin/bash
UNIQUEOBJECT=$(for i in *.*
do
    echo "$i"
done | cut -d '_' -f 1 | sort -u)
echo "$UNIQUEOBJECT"
```

You need to generate the list before you sort.  Your original was generating the list after sorting.